# command D in sed - output seems different from what the manual says

Tags: sed

Found the following in the sed manual about the command D,

**D** - If pattern space contains no newline, start a normal new cycle as if the d command was issued.  Otherwise,  **delete  text  in the pattern space up to the first newline, and restart cycle with the resultant pattern space, without reading a new line of input**

But the example I try do not seem to match what is described above.

```
$cat test
LINE 101
LINE 201
LINE 301
LINE 401

$ sed -nr '1{p;N;p;D;}' test
LINE 101
LINE 101
LINE 201
```

The way I understood based on the sed manual description is as follows,

1. print the pattern space (LINE 101)
2. Append LINE 201 to the pattern space print the pattern space (LINE 101 \n LINE 201)
3. Delete up to the first new line in the pattern space. The pattern
   space will now have LINE 201
4. Now sed manual says "and restart cycle with the resultant pattern space, without reading a new line of input" - That would mean go back to the beginning of the command? If that's how it is, then we should have an output of - LINE 201, LINE 201 \n LINE 301 and on like that in a loop till the end.

But that's not the output I see.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what output you expect, but you're using the 'n' option, which will suppress all output -- except in the first cycle, when you explicitly ask for it.

Comment: In your example there are 4 lines. The automatic printing of a line at the end of cycle is switched off (`-n`) and the commands are limited to the first line by the address `1`. The first line is printed (`p`) and the second line appended (`N`). Lines 1 and 2 are printed again (`p`)  and the first line deleted. No further processing is done, since the current line number is now 2 or more. BTW the `-r` option is not necessary as no regexps are present.

Comment: I intentionally turned on the -n flag to suppress default echoing. My point it that the output doesn't match what the man page says D will do, "delete text in the pattern space up to the first newline, and restart cycle with the resultant pattern space, without reading a new line of input". Since apparently it is not reading a new line of input 1{ } shouldn't make it stop. I left -r in there since I was testing. Saw the usage of D in some code I was looking over at work and wanted to know how D exactly works.

Comment: After the first cycle has been processed, sed has the line number at 2. Although the pattern space still contains `LINE 201`, processing is restricted to the addess/line number 1. With automatic printing turned off, no further printing will occur. Try removing the line 1 address i.e. `sed -n 'p;N;p;D' file`. This will print line 1, then 1 and 2, 2, 2 and 3, 3, 3 and 4, 4 and then the `N` will try to read past the eof and will terminate.

Comment: I got the answer...saw this in Daniel Goldman's book on sed. "sed maintains a line counter.... n and N commands increments the line counter". That explains it

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is contained in @potong's comment already.

Concerning why the OP was surprised by `sed`'s behavior, I can only speculate that it is due to the wording of his point 2:

> Append LINE 201 to the pattern space print the pattern space (LINE 101
>   \n LINE 201)

which leaves room for the following wrong interpretation:

> `N` *picks* the next line of input and appends it to the current
>   pattern space (with a newline in between); then, when the end of
>   script is reached, the same next line of input is *read*.

This would mean that `LINE 201` is processed twice. On the contrary, it is processed only once, as `N` **reads a new line** of input **and appends it** to the content of the pattern space.